# C - Accessing linked list inside of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list of students, where each student has a linked list of grades. I am stuck trying to access a student's grades using the data structure below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100

typedef struct student_list_struct{
    char student[MAX];
    struct grades_list_struct *grade_head_ptr;
    struct student_list_struct *next;
} StudentNode;

typedef struct grades_list_struct{
    int grade;
    struct student_list_struct *next;
} GradeNode;

GradeNode *insertGrade(int grade, GradeNode *head){
    GradeNode *newNode=NULL;
    newNode=(GradeNode*)calloc(1, sizeof(GradeNode));

    if(head!=NULL){
        newNode->grade=grade;
        return newNode;
    } else {
        newNode->grade=grade;
        newNode->next=NULL;
        return newNode;
    }
}

StudentNode *insertStudent(char studentName[MAX], int studentGrade, StudentNode *head){
    StudentNode *newNode=NULL;
    newNode=(StudentNode*)calloc(1, sizeof(StudentNode));
    newNode->grade_head_ptr=(GradeNode*)calloc(1, sizeof(GradeNode));

    if (head==NULL){
        strcpy(newNode->student, studentName);
        newNode->next=NULL;
        newNode->grade_head_ptr=insertGrade(studentGrade, newNode->grade_head_ptr);
        return newNode;
    } else {
        strcpy(newNode->student, studentName);
        newNode->grade_head_ptr->grade=studentGrade;
        newNode->grade_head_ptr=insertGrade(studentGrade, newNode->grade_head_ptr);
        return newNode;
    }
}

void printGrades(char studentName[MAX], StudentNode *head){
    StudentNode *p=NULL;
    p=head;

    while (p!=NULL){
        if (strcmp(p->student,studentName)==0){
            printf("%d\n", p->grade_head_ptr->grade);
        }
        p->grade_head_ptr=p->grade_head_ptr->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    StudentNode *head=NULL;
    StudentNode *temp=NULL;

    head=insertStudent("Student A", 10, head);
    head=insertStudent("Student A", 20, head);
    printGrades("Student A", head);
}
```

It currently does not print or return anything, and I can't figure out what is wrong with my data structure. It might have to do with the way I am trying to access the grade using `head->grade_head_ptr->grade`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't allocate `grade_head_ptr` pointer before use it in function insertStudent. It will cause the segmentation fault.
So, please use after  allocating the `newNode` pointer in this function.

```
newNode->grade_head_ptr = (GradeNode*)calloc(1, sizeof(GradeNode));
```

for allocating the memory for `grade_head_ptr`
Here is entire the function `insertStudent`

```
StudentNode *insertStudent(char studentName[100], int studentGrade, StudentNode *head) {
    StudentNode *newNode = NULL;
    newNode = (StudentNode*)calloc(1, sizeof(StudentNode));
    newNode->grade_head_ptr = (GradeNode*)calloc(1, sizeof(GradeNode));

    if (head == NULL) {
        strcpy(newNode->student, studentName);
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->grade_head_ptr->grade = studentGrade;
        newNode->grade_head_ptr->next = NULL;
        return newNode;
    }
    else {
        strcpy(newNode->student, studentName);
        newNode->grade_head_ptr->grade = studentGrade;
        return newNode;
    }
}
```

For using `insertStudent`, you are using the string literal "Student A", it will report compiler error because it understood it is const char* that is incompatible with your function prototype. So please use a character array and assigned the "Student A" value:

```
    char studentName[] = "Student A";
    head = insertStudent(studentName, 10, head);
```

It should work then.

Comment: Thank you, I want to be able to add multiple grades under a student, and to print out those grades. However, I get a warning: `warning: assignment to 'struct grades_list_struct *' from incompatible pointer type 'struct student_list_struct *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]` for `p->grade_head_ptr=p->grade_head_ptr->next;` in the `printGrades` function. How can I fix this? I updated the code above.

Comment: Did you add more requirement in your question? so in that case, please create another question?

Comment: No problem. On the same note as your response above, why do we have to allocate memory for `grade_head_ptr` even though that memory has been allocated under `insertGrades()`?

Comment: A separate post was created here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54812582/c-nested-linked-lists