# C - Nested linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list of students, each with a linked list of grades, but I'm having trouble accessing the linked list of grades inside the linked list of students.

```
typedef struct student_data_struct{
    char student[MAX];
    struct grades_list_struct *gradeP;
} student_Data;

typedef struct student_list_struct{
    student_Data studentData;
    struct student_list_struct *next;
} StudentNode;

typedef struct grades_list_struct{
    int grade;
    struct grades_list_struct *next;
} GradeNode;

GradeNode *insertGrade(int grade, GradeNode *head){
    GradeNode *newNode=NULL;
    newNode=(GradeNode*)calloc(1, sizeof(GradeNode));

    if(head!=NULL){
        newNode->grade=grade;
        newNode->next=head;
        return newNode;
    } else {
        newNode->grade=grade;
        newNode->next=NULL;
        return newNode;
    }
}

StudentNode *insertStudent(char studentName[MAX], int studentGrade, StudentNode *head){
    StudentNode *newNode=NULL;
    newNode=(StudentNode*)calloc(1, sizeof(StudentNode));
    newNode->studentData->gradeP=(GradeNode*)calloc(1, sizeof(GradeNode));

    if (head==NULL){
        strcpy(newNode->studentData.student, studentName);
        newNode->next=NULL;
        newNode->studentData->gradeP=insertGrade(studentGrade, newNode->studentData->gradeP);
        return newNode;
    } else {
        strcpy(newNode->student, studentName);
        newNode->gradeP->grade=studentGrade;
        newNode->studentData->gradeP=insertGrade(studentGrade, newNode->studentData->gradeP);
        return newNode;
    }
}
```

When I try to allocate memory to the grade pointer,

```
newNode->studentData->gradeP=(GradeNode*)calloc(1, sizeof(GradeNode));
```

I get the error:

```
error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'student_Data' {aka 'struct student_data_struct'})
```

As well, when I try to insert a grade for a student,

```
newNode->studentData->gradeP=insertGrade(studentGrade, newNode->studentData->gradeP);
```

I get the error:

```
error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'student_Data' {aka 'struct student_data_struct'})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing a struct member with pointer symbol. Try writing as given below:-

```
newNode->studentData.gradeP=(GradeNode*)calloc(1, sizeof(GradeNode));

newNode->studentData.gradeP=insertGrade(studentGrade, newNode->studentData.gradeP);
```

Comment: The dot should come after `studentData`, not before it. `newNode` is a pointer, `studentData` is not.

Answer (score 0):

`studentData` is of struct type and is not a pointer to a struct. Hence, the member access operator of a struct(`.`) has to be used instead of an operator to access members of pointer to a struct(`->`).